# Magento 1.9.1 Not able to edit file in the checkout folder

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I added some custom fields in the checkout section. But while i try to update the code in the folder

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/onepage.php
```

I couln't update anything. The code remains the same before showing the last edit date and time as 2014

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess from the information provided.

If developing on a Windows (case-insensitive filesystem) and upload to a Linux (case-sensitive filesystem) Magento might be using the core file.  ie.  onepage.php versus Onepage.php

Note: Directly modifying Magento core files is highly discouraged.  It's possible to override/rewrite core files via a custom module.

Magento Community: https://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: No. That is not the problem. I tried editing the file content directly.

Comment: More details might be helpful.

Comment: Another thought is some APC or OpCache can be configured to not check for updates.  This is often done in production to help speed Magento since it contains so many PHP files. If configured this was you need to reload php-fpm or graceful apache to see changes to PHP files.  

Or are you saying you directly edited the file on the server the filesystem is reporting no change in modified date or file size? no error?